# Linux test expression

Tags: shell, ksh

I'm working a project with 20 year old code that's been patched dozens of times.

There's a test expression I've never seen before and I can't figure out how to break down what it's actually doing.

There's a date variable whose format is either 'YYYYMMDD' or 'YYYYMMMDD' (e.g. '20160629' or '2016JUN29').

The test is:

```
if [[ $datevar != *[0-9] ]]
then
<error notification>
exit 1
fi
```

Can someone explain what the '*[0-9]' expression is doing?  AFAICT no matter what the $date var contains, it never takes the error exit.  Based on the code that generates the date, it should be in the 'YYYYMMMDD' format.

This code originally ran on Sun Solaris, but is now running on RHEL 6.4 using the ksh shell.

Comment: Looks like a very liberal validation to me? If $datevar contains anything (*) followed by a digit of [0-9] you pass, probably why everything passes

Comment: Could you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we can say is that the test is checking that the last char is a number

```
$ datevar=20160629
$ if [[ $datevar != *[0-9] ]] ; then
    echo caught error
  fi
# no output from above

$ datevar=20160629X
$ if [[ $datevar != *[0-9] ]] ; then
    echo caught error
  fi
caught error
$
```

Personally, I prefer using `case` statements for this sort of validation.

```
case $datevar in 
  2[0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-3][0-9] ) : nothing_to_do_correct_format ;; 
  * ) echo error in format for $datevar ;; 
esac
```

This gives you an idea, but doesn't solve for either format AND of course, it doesn't trap invalid month values, as it will match `AAA` to `ZZZ` ;-).

Making it match all possible abbreviations is a consulting project I'm afraid ;-)

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

The expression matches everything that contains a digit at the end, or where a digit is the only character.

In your case, if statement tests reversed logic. Not ends with digit and digit is not last character.